# Parsing the hour only

Tags: javascript, datetime, d3.js

I'm using d3 v3 to parse some intraday data that has the following format:

```
time,value
09:00,1
09:05,2
09:10,3
...
```

So I set up a parsing variable like so:

```
var parseTime = d3.time.format("%H:%M").parse;
```

And I map the data within the scope of the csv call:

```
d3.csv("my_data.csv", function(error, rawData) {
    var data = rawData.map(function(d) {
        return {y_value: +d.value, date: parseTime(d.time)}
    });

    console.log(data)
}
```

In the console, I get something strange. Instead of only the hour, I get the full-fledged date, day of the week, month, even time zone.

```
data->
array[79]
    0:Object->
        date: Mon Jan 01 1900 09:00:00 GMT+0000
        y_value: 1
```

Do dates *need* to be this complete? I suppose that could explain why I wound up with monday Jan. 1st, seems like a default of sorts. However, according to [d3 time documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format/blob/master/README.md#user-content-locale_format), `"%H:%M"` is used for hours and minutes. And I could have sworn I did that much correct.

I know something is not quite right because my line graph is throwing the error:

```
error: <path> attribute d: expected number "MNaN"
```

My best guess is that the date is over-specified and the `axis()` is expecting an hour format.

**My Question is:** Why isn't my data being parsed as hour only? Should I change this from the parsing end? If that's not an option, can I have the x domain read a portion of the date (the hour and minute portion)?

**Update:** Here is a [minimal block](http://bl.ocks.org/diggetybo/9d257b6e99f158dbc81ac8216f8adc5a) for further illustration of my plight.

Comment: Hi Arash - .parse will return a date object, and yes, will default to 01/01/1900 if not specified in the incoming data. This will be OK,but you'll need to share your code for your scale and path function so we can see where the error lies.

Comment: Indeed, without the scale and the line generator we cannot find the problem. However, I believe that your main problem here is conceptual... have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say...

> why isn't my data being parsed as hour only?

... it becomes evident that there is a basic misunderstanding here. Let's clarify it.

#### What is a date?

Simply put, a date is a moment in time. It can be *now*, or two months ago, or the day my son was born, or next Christmas, or the moment Socrates drank the hemlock. It does'n matter. What is important to understand is that all those dates have a century, a decade, a year, a month, a day, an hour, a minute, a second, a millisecond etc... (of course, those names are conventions that can be changed).

Therefore, it makes little sense having a *date* with just the hour, or just the hour and the minute.

#### Parsing and formating

When you **parse** a string, you create a *date object*. As we explained above, that date object corresponds to a moment in time, and it will have year, month, hour, timezone etc... If the string itself lacks some information, as *year* for instance, it will default to some value.

Look at this demo, we will **parse** a string into a date object, using the correct specifier:

```js
var string = "09:00";
var parser = d3.timeParse("%H:%M");
var date = parser(string);
console.log("The date object is: " + date);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

As you can see, we have a date object now. By the way, you can see that it defaults to a given year (1900), a given month (January), and so on...

However, in your chart, you don't need to show the *entire* object, that is, all the information regarding that moment in time. You can show just hour and minute, for instance. We will **format** that date.

Have a look:

```js
var string = "09:00";
var parser = d3.timeParse("%H:%M");
var format = d3.timeFormat("%H:%M");
var date = parser(string);
console.log("The date object is: " + date);
console.log("The formatted date is: " + format(date));
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

That formatted date is useful for creating axes, tooltips, texts etc..., that is, showing the date you have without showing **all** its details. You can choose what information you want to show to the user (just the year, or just the month, or maybe day-month-year, whatever).

That's the difference between *parsing* and *formatting*.

#### Why using a formatter?

To finalise, you may ask: *why am I using a formatter, if I will end up having the same thing I had at the beginning?*

The answer is: you don't have the same thing. Now you have a *date*, not a string. And, using a date with a time scale, you can accomodate daylight savings, leap years, February with only 28 days, that is, a bunch of things that are impossible to do with a simple string.

PS: The demos above use D3 v4.

---

EDIT: After your **update** we can easily see the problem with your code: you have to pass an **array** to `range()`.

```
var xScale = d3.time.scale().range([0,width]);
```

Here is the updated bl.ocks: http://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/a05e15339f7792f175d2bcebccf6bbed/7f23db481f1308eb0d5a1834f7cbc0b17d948167

Comment: Your answer clears things up so much, I did misunderstand how date formatting works. Thank you for the detailed walk-through. I have updated the post with a minimalist block for reference. I'd like to say I followed your time formatting procedure correctly, but I still get that path error.

Comment: Your problem here is way simpler: **range** has to be an array. Here is the updated bl.ocks: http://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/a05e15339f7792f175d2bcebccf6bbed/7f23db481f1308eb0d5a1834f7cbc0b17d948167